# pn512 debug transmit command

Tags: nfc

I am trying to use the transmit command of the pn512, (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PN512.pdf 19.3.1.5) in NFC-Target mode.

After filling the FIFO and setting the command the FIFO is empty, but nothing is happening on the air.

I checked the error register, and there is no error.

Do you have any idea, what might went wrong, or how to debug this further?

Comment: There are two programs on the NXP site, that might help you, the Basic Function Library and the Joiner PC Serial. Both have examples how to setup the chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Transmitting the Modulation has to be inverted by setting the respective bit in the TxMode Register